# Javascript E4X: How do I properly iterate over an attribute XMLList?

Tags: javascript, iteration, attributes, undefined, e4x

I have a problem with retrieving attribute values via E4x in javascript.

Suppose a list of XML nodes like the following as the XMLObject:

```
<node att1="value1" att2="value2" att3="value3" att4="value4">
    <nodeChild><!CDATA[/* ... */]></nodeChild>
    /* more node childs */
</node>
```

I properly accessed the nodes (in a loop) and its attribute nodes using the `attributes()` method:

```
var attributes = node[n].attributes() ;
    for(var n = 0 ; n < attributes.length() ; n++) {
        var name = attributes[n].name() ;
        var value = attributes[n].toString() ;
        //.. handle the values
    }
```

Now, for one, names and values are not adequately returned value(n) returns the value of name(n+1), i.e. the value of `att1` will be `value2` ; if I set `var value = attributes[ (n+1) ].toString()` the values are returned correctly but the first value will return `undefined`.

Possible I'm just dense on this one. So, does anyone have any pointers to what I am missing?

TIA,

FK

Comment: I'm not sure about what's going on here, but is "name" really a function, and not just a simple string?

Comment: Yes, it is—E4X is weird and behaves differently to how you'd expect a normal DOM or JS object to. The example works fine for me, except for it not being clear where the `n` comes from in `node[n].attributes()`. Of course if `//.. handle the values` alters the attributes there's potentially a destructive iteration problem.

Comment: The above is pseudo-code. My use case (JS xml parsing function in Rhino used in a Java class) is far more complex, so I abstracted the problem. I should have stated that. Sorry.

Comment: @ Pointy: `name()` is a method of the XMLObject in E4X that yields the node name. In this case the attribute name.

Comment: @ bobince: I'm not changing the values. If there is no obvious error in the loop syntax, the error must be somewhere else in the code. I'll go through it and---in case---will post additional code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works for me, apart from these gotchas which I'm sure don't exist in your actual XML since you are able to parse and iterate through them:

1. CDATA declaration wasn't valid. Changed to `<![CDATA[..]]>`
2. `/* more node childs */` makes the XML invalid
3. Replaced `n` with `0`, or could do without it altogether

Here's the exact code I used to iterate the node attributes.

```
var node = <node att1="value1" att2="value2" att3="value3" att4="value4">
    <nodeChild><![CDATA[/* ... */]]></nodeChild>
</node>;

var attributes = node[0].attributes() ;
for(var n = 0 ; n < attributes.length() ; n++) {
    var name = attributes[n].name() ;
    var value = attributes[n].toString() ;
    console.log("%s = %s", name, value);    
}

// log output
// att1 = value1
// att2 = value2
// att3 = value3
// att4 = value4
```

Note that E4X provides a more succinct way of writing the above (combined with `for each in` introduced in [JavaScript 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/new_in_javascript_1.6#For_each_..._in)):

```
for each(var attribute in node.@*) {
    var name = attribute.name();
    var value = attribute.toString();
}
```

Since you are referring to an XML object, there is no need to reference the root element by index as in `node[0]`. You can simply write `node`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's pseudo code, my actual xml is valid. I believe the `for each in` syntax isn't available in `Rhino` (as it does not yet include JavaScript 1.6). I'm using E4X in a JS function called from a Rhino context. Did you use my `for loop` in your test?

Comment: I didn't test it on Rhino, but I did test your for loop version with the changes I mentioned - basically the exact same code I've pasted above, on Firefox.

Comment: Alright, the error must be somewhere else then. Good thing to know that I don't fail at writing basic syntax. :-) Thanks.